# Shadow Mapping OpenGL shadow not always drawing, and drawing where the position of the light is

Tags: c++, opengl, framebuffer, shadow-mapping

I have been trying to do basic Shadow Mapping in my custom Engine using LearnOpenGL as the source. The link for the exact tutorial can be found: [here](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Shadows/Shadow-Mapping).

I have been debugging this bug for around two weeks, researching the internet, and even trying to wrap my head around this, but all I can say is that the shadow almost never appears, and when it appears it is where the light is Pos is terms of x and z. I tried to do everything exactly like in the tutorial around 10 times, I also tried to check this website for similar questions but for every way I found, it was not my case.

## findings

In this [Image(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVXtU.jpg) you can see that the shadow is not visible when the light is on top of it, but it is then visible on this [Image (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CguB.jpg) when the lightPos.x variable is around -4.5 or 4.5, this is so for the lightPos.z variable too. The shadow when appearing is being drawn where the lightPos is, where in the pictures it is circled by a red line.

I use multiple shaders, one for the light and shadow calculations (ShadowMapping) one for a basic depth mapping (ShadowMapGen)
Here is my ShadowMapping shader:

## ShadowMapping Vertex

```
version 460
in vec3 vertexIn;
in vec3 normalIn;
in vec2 textureIn;

out vec3 FragPos;
out vec3 normalOut;
out vec2 textureOut;

out vec4 FragPosLightSpace;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 lightSpaceMatrix;

void main()
{
    textureOut = textureIn;

    FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(vertexIn, 1.0));
    normalOut = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * normalIn;  
    FragPosLightSpace = lightSpaceMatrix * vec4(FragPos, 1.0);    

    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(vertexIn, 1.0);
}
```

## ShadowMapping Frag

```
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 FragPos;
in vec3 normalOut;
in vec2 textureOut;

in vec4 FragPosLightSpace;

uniform sampler2D diffuseTexture;
uniform sampler2D shadowMap;

uniform vec3 lightPos;
uniform vec3 viewPos;

float ShadowCalculation(vec4 fragPosLightSpace, vec3 lightdir)
{
    // perform perspective divide
    vec3 projCoords = fragPosLightSpace.xyz / fragPosLightSpace.w;
    // transform to [0,1] range
    projCoords = projCoords * 0.5 + 0.5;
    // get closest depth value from light's perspective (using [0,1] range fragPosLight as coords)
    float closestDepth = texture(shadowMap, projCoords.xy).r; 
    // get depth of current fragment from light's perspective
    float currentDepth = projCoords.z;
    // check whether current frag pos is in shadow
    float bias = max(0.05 * (1.0 - dot(normalOut, lightdir)), 0.005);

    // check whether current frag pos is in shadow
//    float shadow = currentDepth - bias > closestDepth  ? 1.0 : 0.0;
//    // PCF
    float shadow = 0.0;

    vec2 texelSize = 1.0 / textureSize(shadowMap, 0);
    for(int x = -1; x <= 1; ++x)
    {
        for(int y = -1; y <= 1; ++y)
        {
            float pcfDepth = texture(shadowMap, projCoords.xy + vec2(x, y) * texelSize).r; 
            shadow += currentDepth - bias > pcfDepth  ? 1.0 : 0.0;        
        }    
    }

    shadow /= 9.0;

    // keep the shadow at 0.0 when outside the far_plane region of the light's frustum.
        if(projCoords.z > 1.0)
        shadow = 0.0;

    return shadow;
}

void main()
{           
    vec3 color = texture(diffuseTexture, textureOut).rgb;
    vec3 normal = normalize(normalOut);
    vec3 lightColor = vec3(1.0f);
    // ambient
    vec3 ambient = 0.30 * color;
    // diffuse
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos - FragPos);
    float diff = max(dot(lightDir, normal), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = diff * lightColor;
    // specular
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
    float spec = 0.0;
    vec3 halfwayDir = normalize(lightDir + viewDir);  
    spec = pow(max(dot(normal, halfwayDir), 0.0), 64.0);
    vec3 specular = spec * lightColor;    
    // calculate shadow
    float shadow = ShadowCalculation(FragPosLightSpace, lightDir);                      
    vec3 lighting = (ambient + (1.0 - shadow) * (diffuse + specular)) * color;    

    FragColor = vec4(lighting, 1.0);
}
```

## ShadowMapGen Vertex

Fragment Shader is empty for this shader

```
version 460

in vec3 vertexIn;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 lightSpaceMatrix;

void main()
{
    gl_Position =  model * lightSpaceMatrix * vec4(vertexIn, 1.0);
}
```

## Variable initialisation

```
lightPos = glm::vec3(-2.0f, 4.0f, -1.0f);
near_plane = 1.0f;
far_plane = 7.5f;

//SAMPLE 2D Uniform binding
TheShader::Instance()->SendUniformData("ShadowMapping_diffuseTexture", 0);
TheShader::Instance()->SendUniformData("ShadowMapping_shadowMap", 1);
```

## Depth Map Framebuffer Generation

This is how I generate my depth map/ shadow map texture in the constructor of my scene:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &depthMapFBO);
//Create depth texture
glGenTextures(1, &depthMap);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMap);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, SHADOW_WIDTH, SHADOW_HEIGHT, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL); // Height and Width = 1024
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);

float borderColor[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, borderColor);

//Attach depth texture as FBO's depth buffer
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthMapFBO);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMap, 0);
glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Then in an Update() function that runs in the While loop of the engine I firstly do:

## Render Objects from light's perspective

```
//Light Projection and view Matrix 
m_lightProjection = glm::ortho(-10.0f, 10.0f, -10.0f, 10.0f, near_plane, far_plane);
m_lightView = glm::lookAt(lightPos, glm::vec3(0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
//Calculate light matrix and send it.
m_lightSpaceMatrix = m_lightProjection * m_lightView;
TheShader::Instance()->SendUniformData("ShadowMapGen_lightSpaceMatrix", 1, GL_FALSE, m_lightSpaceMatrix);

//Render to Framebuffer depth Map
glViewport(0, 0, SHADOW_WIDTH, SHADOW_HEIGHT);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthMapFBO);
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

//Set current Shader to ShadowMapGen
m_floor.SetShader("ShadowMapGen");
m_moon.SetShader("ShadowMapGen");
//Send model Matrix to current Shader
m_floor.Draw();
m_moon.Draw();
//Set current Shader back to ShadowMapping
m_moon.SetShader("ShadowMapping");
m_floor.SetShader("ShadowMapping");

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

## Render Objects from Camera's perspective

```
glViewport(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
//Update Camera and Send the view and projection matrices to the ShadowMapping shader
m_freeCamera->Update();
m_freeCamera->Draw();

//Send Light Pos 
TheShader::Instance()->SendUniformData("ShadowMapping_lightPos", lightPos);
//Send LightSpaceMatrix
TheShader::Instance()->SendUniformData("ShadowMapping_lightSpaceMatrix", 1, GL_FALSE, m_lightSpaceMatrix);

//Activate Shadow Mapping texture
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMap);

//Send model Matrix to ShadowMapping shaders
m_moon.Draw();  
m_floor.Draw();
```

I hope someone will see this, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to do everything exactly like in the tutorial around 10 times

Well, you seem to have missed at least one obvious thing:

> ```
> m_lightSpaceMatrix = m_lightProjection * m_lightView;
> ```

So far, so good, but in your "ShadowMapGen" vertex shader, you wrote:

> ```
> gl_Position =  model * lightSpaceMatrix * vec4(vertexIn, 1.0);
> ```

So you end up with `model * projection * view` multiplication order, which does not make sense no matter which conventions you adhere to. Since the tutorial uses default GL conventions, you always need `projection * view * model * vertex` multiplication order, which the tutorial also correctly uses.

Comment: Just tested, and it works. Yes, you are right, I can't believe I overlooked this small detail. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Didn't cost me much time, was the very first thing I looked at... :)